# fade out and show jquery buttons work in normal index.html but not in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-selectors

This is probably a dum error that can be fixed in seconds but have been looking for a while and dont know how to make it work

I essentially had this code
`

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   .box,
   button { float:left; margin:5px 10px 5px 0; }
   .box { height:80px; width:80px; background:#090; }
   #log { clear:left; }

   </style>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <button id="btn1">fade out</button>
   <button id="btn2">show</button>

   <div id="log"></div>

   <div id="box1" class="box">linear</div>
   <div id="box2" class="box">swing</div>

   <script>
   $("#btn1").click(function() {
     function complete() {
       $("<div/>").text(this.id).appendTo("#log");
     }

     $("#box1").fadeOut(1600, "linear", complete);
     $("#box2").fadeOut(1600, complete);
   });

   $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("div").show();
     $("#log").empty();
   });

   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

`
So then I wanted to make it work in wordpress so I moved the style to a css  and the  to the footer.php  as you can see here

`

```
                <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
                <script>
$("#btn1").click(function() {
function complete() {
$("<div/>").text(this.id).appendTo("#log");
}

$("#box1").fadeOut(1600, "linear", complete);
$("#box2").fadeOut(1600, complete);
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
$("#box1").show();
$("#box2").show();
$("#log").empty();
});

</script>
```

`

http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/testpage/

But it does not work I have placed the wp_enquenue  and everything I could see as a potential problem like interference on different versions of jquery but dont know what is causing the problem the only thing I know is that one time I put the line      within the pages html code and it worked. Until the visual editor got rid of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a javascript error.

/testpage/:233  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null

You need to initialize jQuery

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#btn1").click(function() {

        function complete() {
          jQuery("<div/>").text(this.id).appendTo("#log");
        }

        jQuery("#box1").fadeOut(1600, "linear", complete);
        jQuery("#box2").fadeOut(1600, complete);
    });

    jQuery("#btn2").click(function() {
    jQuery("#box1").show();
    jQuery("#box2").show();
    jQuery("#log").empty();
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry if I sound like a newb  but is that for wordpress and if so how do I put the code in the page so you can see what I have  http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/testpage/

Comment: It is for wordpress, just wrap your code in $(function(){   });

Comment: wold it be something like this
    <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
$(function(){
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#btn1").click(function() {

        function complete() {
          jQuery("<div/>").text(this.id).appendTo("#log");
        }

        jQuery("#box1").fadeOut(1600, "linear", complete);
        jQuery("#box2").fadeOut(1600, complete);
    });

    jQuery("#btn2").click(function() {
    jQuery("#box1").show();
    jQuery("#box2").show();
    jQuery("#log").empty();
    });
});
});

its in site as well sorry its first time placing in wordpress